# mapping list source to target

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I have an object organization that contains a contact objects list. 
The conacts list exists already in the database.

To test with postman, when i need to add an organization i have to add the list of contacts id

```
{
 "name": "ce",
 "contactsId": [1, 3]
}
```

In the contact class i have

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "contact_organization", joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "contacts_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organizations_id",  referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Organization> organizations = new HashSet<>();
```

In the Organization class i have

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "organizations")
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<>();
```

and in the organisationDTO class i have

```
private Set<Long> contactsId = new HashSet<>();
```

In the mapping class i did the mapping this way but it doesn't seem to be working

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { ContactMapper.class }))
public interface OrganizationMapper extends EntityMapper<OrganizationDTO, Organization> {

  @Mapping(source = "contacts", target = "contactsId")
  OrganizationDTO toDto(Organization organization);

  @Mapping(source = "contactsId", target = "contacts")
  Organization toEntity(OrganizationDTO organizationDTO);

  default Organization fromId(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
     return null;
    }
    Organization organization = new Organization();
    organization.setId(id);
    return organization;
  }

  default Long fromContact(Contact contact) {
    return contact == null ? null : contact.getId();
  }
}

 @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { OrganizationMapper.class })
public interface ContactMapper extends EntityMapper<ContactDTO, Contact> {

 ContactDTO toDto(Contact contact);

 Contact toEntity(ContactDTO contactDTO);

 default Contact fromId(Long id) {
   if (id == null) {
    return null;
   }
   Contact contact = new Contact();
   contact.setId(id);
   return contact;
 }
}
```

the problem here it shows me the id and the label is null, and in the data base it adds the organization but does not add the contacts

```
Organization organization = organizationMapper.toEntity(organizationDTO);
for(Contact item : organization.getContacts()) {
  log.info("******************************************" + item.getId());
  log.info("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + item.getLabel());
}
organization = organizationRepository.save(organization);
```

Answer (score 0):

This currently is not supported. You are trying to map a property `id` from the list `contacts` into the `contactsId` list.

In order to achieve what you are looking forward you need to provide a way of mapping from `Contact` to `Long`.
Your mapper can look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "contacts", target = "contactsId")
    OrganizationDTO toDto(Organization organization);

    default Long fromContact(Contact contact) {
        return contact == null ? null : contact.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case the mapping is worked, but it displays only the ids of the contact class and the other attribute is null, i want when i give the id it returns all the objects with the attribute

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you. Which direction of mapping are you referring to?

Comment: I modified my question above